# Why doctors allow several MMA fights in the same night but not in a few days?

Tags: mma

I read on https://www.bjpenn.com/mma-news/ufc/donald-cerrone-wants-to-become-first-ufc-fighter-to-fight-three-times-in-one-week/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201228214340/https://www.bjpenn.com/mma-news/ufc/donald-cerrone-wants-to-become-first-ufc-fighter-to-fight-three-times-in-one-week/)):

> Even if he wants to do it, doctors, not to mention UFC officials, might not let him. Then again, maybe they actually give him a chance to accomplish his goal.

Why doctors allow several MMA fights in the same night but not in a few days?

Comment: Can you include why you suggest it might be permissible in a single night?  Are you referring to the `single-night tournaments` the article refers to having taken place in "early" UFC days?

Comment: @Joe yes, Pride too. Also PFL/Bellator are looking into organizing one-night tournament.

Comment: Can you include links to that in the question?  It seems to me like the article contradicts your thesis here (suggesting that, in the "current" UFC, this is not permitted).  Of course, why that *changed* could be an interesting question, perhaps (I know nothing about the UFC, so I don't know myself.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://www.iscfmma.com/ISCFRules15.htm ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201230233242/https://www.iscfmma.com/ISCFRules15.htm#:%7E:text=Minimum%2520of%252030%2520days%2520to%2520120%2520Day%2520Medical%2520Recovery%2520Suspension,days%2520to%2520the%2520fighter%2520injured.)) gives the explanation:

**Time Between Bouts**
This new rule is to avoid a fighter, fighting on a "*Different Promotional*" event less then 7 days after a fight or a fighter fighting too soon after being defeated by a Knock Out or TKO by too many striking blows.

- If the fighter is fighting in a TOURNAMENT within a 3 day time span and does not lose by KO/TKO and is not cut or injured during their bout, the "Time Between Bout" Rule does not apply.

  - **6-08:** Fighters in a TOURNAMENT MUST be checked by a Licensed MD after EACH BOUT to assure they are in good health to continue to the next round.
- **TIME BETWEEN BOUTS**

  - 7 days or 168 Hours before stepping into the ring or cage to fight again.

    - **Example:** If you fight on Friday night the 1st at 6:PM, you cannot fight again until the following weekend, Friday night the 8th at 6:01 PM

      - There are other reasons for this rule as well. These reasons will also explain why a fighter can fight multiple times within 2-3 days if only on the SAME event. Such as;

        - It stops a fighter from booking back to back fights where as the second fight's promoter risks him not being on his event if injured the week before.
        - It gives the sanctioning bodies and the MMA Databases a chance to make sure all the fighters results are made public. An amateur fighter could fight as a pro and turn around and fight as an amateur a week later because the news had not gotten out yet he fought pro.
    - **FINE & SUSPENSION:** If ANY AMATEUR fighter is caught breaking this rule, by fighting for another organization or on an unsanctioned event within 7 days of an **ISCF** Sanctioned event, that fighter will be suspended from competing by the **ISCF** for a minimum of 60 days and fined a Medical Rest Period Fine of $250.00. *Suspension will remain until fine is paid.*